# Fast method to initialize my array

Tags: c

I have an array of int and i have to initialize this array with the value -1. For now i use this loop:

```
int i;
int myArray[10];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    myArray[i] = -1;
```

There are faster ways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quickest way I know for the value `-1` (or `0`) is [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/):

```
int v[10];
memset(v, -1, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

Anyway you can optimize the loop in this way:

```
int i;
for(i = 10; i--;)
    v[i] = -1;
```

Comment: On two's complement machines. Won't work on exotic stuff like sign-and-magnitude. But since all the world nowadays is two's complement, yes.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to initialize the array at the time of declaration with 0, you can use:
`int a[10] = {0};` which is very fast. But if you want to initialize with some other value or want to re-initialize your array with 0 at some point later in the code, use:
`memset(a, -1, size_a);` (or `memset(a, 0, size_a);` respectively) or a loop. In my opinion, always prefer `memset()` to looping because `memset()` is often optimized to set entire words in memory to the initialization value given as its argument instead of setting individual bytes.

For stats, on my 32-bit Linux installation with 4GB memory and 2.2GHz*2 processor, the running times of four types of array initialization codes are given below:

1). 0.002s

```
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1000000

int a[SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

2). 0.008s

```
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1000000

int main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE] = {0};
    return 0;
}
```

3). 0.003s

```
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1000000

int main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE];
    memset(a, -1, SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

4). 0.011s

```
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1000000

int main(void)
{
    int a[SIZE];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        a[i] = -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The simple allocation loop will be optimized into a call to `memset` by any sane optimizing compiler.

Comment: Yes, with `-O2` or with `-O3`, gcc 4.5.2 does optimize the allocation loop to `memset()`-like assembly code.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` is very fast.

```
int arr[10];
memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr));
```

However, what you have there will likely be turned into a call to memset by an optimizing compiler anyway. Look at your assembly output to make sure, but it is highly unlikely that the loop will remain a loop when compiled.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU C what you can do is:

```
int myArray[10] = {[0 ... 9] = -1};
```

Initializing a range of elements: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

And as nobody mentioned it, in portable C:

```
int myArray[10] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

Comment: @Nick This is not C but a GNU extension to C (enabled by default with gcc).